# How to use Algolia places in next.js?

Tags: typescript, next.js, algolia

I am trying to implement algolia places to my next.js, typescript project.

1. I run `npm install places.js --save`
2. I put `<input type="search" id="address-input" placeholder="Where are we going?" />` into my component.

```
const Algolia = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="search"
        id="address-input"
        placeholder="Where are we going?"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Algolia;
```

3.I am stuck. I don't know how to initialize the places.js library.
I don't where to put

```
var places = require('places.js');
var placesAutocomplete = places({
  appId: <YOUR_PLACES_APP_ID>,
  apiKey: <YOUR_PLACES_API_KEY>,
  container: document.querySelector('#address-input')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your code below in useEffect

```
var placesAutocomplete = places({
  appId: <YOUR_PLACES_APP_ID>,
  apiKey: <YOUR_PLACES_API_KEY>,
  container: document.querySelector('#address-input')
});
```

That way you are sure that it is initialised once the component is loaded in browser.

I would recommend though that you pass element by reference using useRef rather than querying DOM.